# How to access profile or system varilables in Porduction in Ionic

Tags: angular8, production-environment, ionic5

I am developing an ionic app and would like to acess profile variable (linux) or enviornment variable (Windows) in production.
In Node we access it with `process.env.variable name`, but how to access those variables in ionic + angular app.

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  api: "endpoint url",
  key: 'key from profile ', //how to access profile var
  user: 'some user',
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this can not be done as straight forward as one might think. The problem is that whatever code you might put the it will only be evaluated at *run-time* - i.e. when executed on the browser - but what you're trying to achieve here is to inject the environment variables at *build-time* - i.e. on the Linux/Windows host the application is built on.

Since the environment of the build host is not included in the final build it can not be accessed at run-time. Therefore you need some kind of preprocessing/pre-build step insert the build-time value of environment variables into the code.

One way to do this would be to dynamically generate your `src/environments/environment.ts` file before invoking `ng build` to include the current values of the build host's environment as literal values. You can then access them as usual anywhere in your code.

See [this blog post](https://medium.com/@ferie/how-to-pass-environment-variables-at-building-time-in-an-angular-application-using-env-files-4ae1a80383c) for an example implementation of this approach.